# TimePickerFragment Not Working

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment, timepicker

According to the official Android Dev [guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers.html), when the user clicks this button, the system calls the following method:

```
public void showTimePickerDialog(View v) {
    DialogFragment newFragment = new TimePickerFragment();
    newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "timePicker");
}
```

However, when I try this in my Fragment Activity, it shows `TimePickerFragment` in red. And prompts that `TimePickerFragment()` cannot be resolved.

These are my imports related to TimePicker :

```
import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.app.DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.DialogFragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.TimePicker;
import android.app.TimePickerDialog;
```

When I try this for `DatePicker`, the `DatePickerFragment` works.

Comment: Did you solved this yet ??

Answer (score 2):

You are using **[getSupportFragmentManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.html#getSupportFragmentManager())** ,So

**Do**

```
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
```

**Don't**

```
import android.app.DialogFragment;
```

Answer (score 1):

- You need to extends `TimepickerFragment` as `DialogFragment`.

  ```
  public class TimepickerFragment extends DialogFragment{

  public TimepickerFragment(){

  }       
  private TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener callback = new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {

  @Override
  public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {         
     Log.i("Selected Time - ",  hourOfDay + ":" + minute);

  }
  };

  public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle bundle){
  int hourOfDay = 01;
  int minute = 01;
  boolean is24HourView = false;
  TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), callback, hourOfDay, minute, is24HourView); 
  return timePickerDialog;
  }
  }
  ```
- And try your code like below to create `TimePickerFragment` dialog.

  ```
   public void showTimePickerDialog(View v) {
    TimePickerFragment newFragment = new TimePickerFragment();
    newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "timePicker");
  }
  ```